# What does the "D:, H:, V:" means in fbset?

Tags: linux, video, embedded, framebuffer

I search many data on web but I can't find what does the "D: 148.500 MHz, H: 67.500 kHz, V: 60.000 Hz" means in the below example?

mode "1920x1080-60"
        # D: 148.500 MHz, H: 67.500 kHz, V: 60.000 Hz
        geometry 1920 1080 1920 3240 32
        timings 6734 148 88 36 4 44 5
        accel false
        rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode

Does parameter "V:" means the vertical fresh frequency?
Does parameter "H:" means the horizontal fresh frequency?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is about video technology and not a software development / programming question.  It is off topic on SO.  "fresh frequency" !?  "refresh" perhaps.

Comment: I'm a software developer working on an embedded linux application, trying to figure out the refresh rate for the primary framebuffer. This is very much a software development question / topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That part of the file is just a sort of comment

- D=Dot clock, or pixel rate
- H=Horizontal, or scanline rate
- V=Vertical, or frame rate

For the meanings of the other lines, see https://linux.die.net/man/5/fb.modes